# Jmeter is failing to retain variable value of thread Group 1 which is required by Thread group2

Tags: junit, jmeter

I have a scenario with Jmeter.
I have injected my Junits to Jmeter.
Junit would look like:

```
public class class1 extends class2{

    @org.junit.Test
    public void method1(){      
        String s;
        method2();
        s = props.getProperty("some_Property_name");    
}

------second Class -------

public class class2 {

    public Properties props = new Properties();

    method2(){    
         // props get loaded here and stores some values
    }    
}
```

I created
=> Thread Group1 with classname - class1 and testMethod = method2. This will load the props.
Second:
=> Thread Group2 with classname = class1 and testMethod = method1 which uses the props value.

When Jmeter was run, props is null when Thread group2 is run.
Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: Found out the solution for above Q. 

We need to declare props as static in class2, so that it maintains only one copy of props.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution for above Q. We need to declare props as static in class2, so that it maintains only one copy of props.